# PIVOT datetime and ORDER column values of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with values which are not in order

| Id | DateTime | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 18:00:00.000 | Stop1 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 08:00:00.000 | Start |
| 3 | 2022-03-01 20:00:00.000 | Stop2 |
| 4 | 2022-03-02 09:00:00.000 | Start |
| 5 | 2022-03-01 10:00:00.000 | Stop2 |
| 6 | 2022-03-02 11:00:00.000 | Finish |
| 7 | 2022-03-01 14:00:00.000 | Start |
| 8 | 2022-03-02 10:00:00.000 | Stop1 |

where Status can be 'Start', 'Stop1', 'Stop2', or 'Finish'.

I need the timeline like this, where the values are pivoted in the order (from the earliest to the latest; id is not relevant at this point)

| Id | Start | Stop1 | Stop2 | Finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 08:00:00 | NULL | 2022-03-01 10:00:00 | NULL |
| 7 | 2022-03-01 14:00:00 | 2022-03-01 18:00:00 | 2022-03-01 20:00:00 | NULL |
| 4 | 2022-03-02 09:00:00 | 2022-03-02 10:00:00 | NULL | 2022-03-02 11:00:00 |

After I PIVOTed it in SQL Server

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Id, DateTime, Status FROM table
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(DateTime)
    FOR Status IN (Start, Stop1, Stop2, Finish)
) p
```

I got

| Id | Start | Stop1 | Stop2 | Finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 08:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | NULL | NULL | 2022-03-01 10:00:00 | NULL |
| 7 | 2022-03-01 14:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | 2022-03-01 18:00:00 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | 2022-03-01 20:00:00 | NULL |
| 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2022-03-02 11:00:00 |
| 8 | NULL | 2022-03-02 10:00:00 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 2022-03-02 09:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

How can I get that timeline?

Comment: how can line 1 (18h00)  be after line 2(08h00)?

Comment: Those are not sorted and ID column doesn't set the order

Comment: I believe he was asking if you could explain "what *is* the order here"?  :)

Comment: Will there always be a `Start`  status ?

Comment: @SOS there's no order. But you can always ORDER BY :)

Comment: @Squirrel for the purpose of this question - yes

Comment: @Ruslan - Yeah, it was a teasing hint that there probably was an order ... "of sorts" :-) I was thinking you needed to sort on "id", but ... then saw John Cappelletti's answer which was a much better idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  The window functions can be invaluable

Also, remember to "FEED" your pivot with only the required columns.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select id = min(case when Status='Start' then ID end) over (partition by Grp)
              ,DateTime
              ,Status 
         From (
                Select *
                      ,Grp = sum( case when [Status]='Start' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by datetime)
                from YourTable
              ) A
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(DateTime) FOR Status IN (Start, Stop1, Stop2, Finish) ) p
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, John. That worked. Very elegant use of Window functions! Great job!